# count the film made by USA. IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, function

```
[['movie_title', 'director_name', 'color', 'duration', 'actor_1_name', 'language', 'country', 'title_year'], ['Avatar', 'James Cameron', 'Color', '178', 'CCH Pounder', 'English', 'USA', '2009'], ["Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End", 'Gore Verbinski', 'Color', '169', 'Johnny Depp', 'English', 'USA', '2007'], ['Spectre', 'Sam Mendes', 'Color', '148', 'Christoph Waltz', 'English', 'UK', '2015'], ['The Dark Knight Rises', 'Christopher Nolan', 'Color', '164', 'Tom Hardy', 'English', 'USA', '2012']]

def feature_counter(input_lst, index, input_str, header_row = False):
    if header_row == True:
        if input_lst[index] == input_str:
            input_lst = input_lst[1:len(input_lst)]
        for each in input_lst:
            num_elt = num_elt + 1
    return num_elt

num_of_us_movies = feature_counter(movie_metadata, 6, 'USA', True)
print(num_of_us_movies)
```

I'm trying to write a code to count the film made by USA.
When I enter this code, I've got IndexError: list index out of range..!
Can you help me with this?

Comment: Actually, part of my last comment was wrong. Your nested list only has 5 items in it, so you can't take the 6th index. There's still the issue that `num_elt` is not initialised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [['movie_title', 'director_name', 'color', 'duration', 'actor_1_name', 'language', 'country', 'title_year'],
 ['Avatar', 'James Cameron', 'Color', '178', 'CCH Pounder', 'English', 'USA', '2009'],
 ["Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End", 'Gore Verbinski', 'Color', '169', 'Johnny Depp', 'English', 'USA', '2007'],
 ['Spectre', 'Sam Mendes', 'Color', '148', 'Christoph Waltz', 'English', 'UK', '2015'],
 ['The Dark Knight Rises', 'Christopher Nolan', 'Color', '164', 'Tom Hardy', 'English', 'USA', '2012']]

count = len([x for x in l if x[6].lower() == 'usa'])
print(count)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. One more thing..! Where " x for x in l" can be used?

Comment: It is a list comprehension syntax. You can use it almost everywhere as a replacement for foo...loop. 
If this had helped upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a list of lists as movie_metadata.

Try `print len(input_lst)`. It's probably be below 6

Comment: It's 5, so that was the reason I got indexerror. Thanks a lot